# How do I convert a xsd:duration in date format in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, format

I have been given a data set that has two rows with dates in the format xsd:duration which python accounts for as a string.
The format looks like PT3H20M (for 3h20min), or PT3H (for 3h) or PT30M (for 30m). How do you convert this format to date so that I can add the times and perform comparisons on them ?
Thanks for any help

EDIT : I'm specifically looking for any built-in package/function that I don't know about that would do that relatively easily.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that:

1. You extract the numbers of hours and minutes using regular
   expression in python.
2. Use a datetime function to convert to UNIX time or another format.
3. Make a comparison or sum.